# White space before an image

Tags: html, css, frontend

There is a white space before the image in the second row. I don’t know why this is happening. 
Margin and padding are fine.

All images are of the same size, but there is white space on the second row before the image. 2 more images can fit in there.

Upon inspecting it's just showing white space from the body. 
No excess margin or padding is there from any of the images.

Used – "float: left;"

The images on the third row and further are fine.
Can someone figure out the issue, why is this happening?

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIhpG.jpg)

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<p>Photo Gallery</p>

<img src="a (1).jpg">
<img src="a (2).jpg">
<img src="a (3).jpg">
<img src="a (4).jpg">
<img src="a (5).jpg">
<img src="a (6).jpg">
<img src="a (7).jpg">
<img src="a (8).jpg">
<img src="a (9).jpg">


</body>
</html>
```

CSS File:

```
img{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
    padding: 0;

}
p{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin-left: 1.66%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1f1f1;   
    width:30%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the images are of different height. The best solution with display block layout will be using a width to the image and setting the `display: inline-block`

```css
img{
    width: 30%;
    /* margin: 1.66%; */
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
p{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin-left: 1.66%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1f1f1;   
    width:30%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Photo Gallery</p>
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
</div
```

Or else you can go for `flex` display. This will ensure that the child elemets are of same height, without explicitly mentioning the height.

```css
.image-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1.66%;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}
.image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
p {
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin-left: 1.66%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Photo Gallery</p>
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will mess up aspect ratio.

Comment: Using flex still mess up aspect ratio.

Comment: @JonnieJS Check my updated solution in flex that will work fine.

Comment: Using flex worked.Thank you so much. Can you please explain what was the issue there because I didn't understand. I'm new to coding here.

Comment: If OP like this [result](https://jsfiddle.net/9ecju7rd/1/embedded/result) thats good.

Comment: @samrat you were using float layout. The issue is that float will try to fit the content to the horizontal section where the the next space is available. When you use image with different height, a new image will find a space just right to the first one. Thats why the image goer to right after the first one.

Comment: @Nitheesh Setting the height property in pixels fixes the issue but is not responsive. But setting the height in % does not fix the issue. Even if I'm setting the height it yet doesn't work with %. I wanted to make it responsive therefore %.

Comment: @samrat why do you want to set height? Setting height for image make the image stretched.

Answer (score 1):

It's the `margin` property.

```css
img{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1.66%;
    padding: 0;
}
 p{
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin-left: 1.66%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f1f1f1;   
    width:30%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Photo Gallery</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
```

Comment: Try adding an image with different dimension inside the list.

Comment: this reduces the space between the rows but it doesn't fix the issue. Check out the next post. Using flex property fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: @samrat the question says that the images have same size.You need to put more effort for different sizes.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou All images are of the same size. Maybe a few pixels difference which is not seen. My mistake. Thank you so much for letting me know.